# C# - Displaying a message before new file is opened

Tags: c#, richtextbox, dialog

I am new to C# and am having a bit of a problem with Dialog Boxes. I have an event listener on a button used to open an existing file in my text editor. The existing file function opens the file etc without any issues.

**The Problem:** I need to display a message to the user stating that anything within the text box will be lost before the OpenFileDialog pops up. Once OK is clicked the OpenFileDialog should appear and clicking cancel will result in a return to the current document.

I can get either of these to work on their own, but not together. Since an if within an if is not feasible, I'm not really sure how to approach this one :s

My Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        rtb.LoadFile(open.FileName,
        RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```

What Needs To Be Added:

```
DialogResult confirm = 
    MessageBox.Show("Your changes will not be saved!", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

if (confirm == DialogResult.OK) 
{
}
else if(confirm == DialogResult.Cancel) 
{
}
```

I really feel like there's some really simple solution I'm missing. Unfortunately I cannot find anything on this. Has been awhile since I last coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DialogResult confirm = 
    MessageBox.Show("Your changes will not be saved!", "Are you sure?", ...)

if (confirm == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        rtb.LoadFile(open.FileName,
        RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
else if(confirm == DialogResult.Cancel) 
{

}
```

Note that in this particular case the `else if` is superflous and can safely be removed.

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I was under the impression that I couldn't nest if statements within each other. I feel like a proper knob. Thanks ByteBlast. Should have gone with my original thought pattern :) I'll accept your answer as soon as time limit is up.